# How to convert a solution from VS2003 to VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio

I have builded a solution in VS2003. Now i want to migrate to VS2003. I know that when I open the VS2003 solution in VS2005 the IDE will convert the solution to VS2005.

But I am getting the following error window when I click on convert in the conversion wizard:

```
e:\Test.vcproj can not be opened because it's project type(vc.proj) is not  
supported  by the version of the application.to open this use a version that support  
this
```

How can I resolve this?

Any help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Your installed version of VS2005 does not include C/C++ support. Reinstall VS2005 and make sure you tick the appropriate checkboxes in the Setup, then you will be able to open `.vcproj` files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of the error in your case, but the only time I've seen errors like this it was because I did not have the appropriate components of Visual Studio installed.  Make sure that your installation is configured with all the components you need and retry. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command using Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt (if you're using Vista, make sure you "Run as Administrator":

```
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

[From here: /ResetSkipPkgs (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276(VS.80).aspx)